# How to pass customer information from magento to codeigniter in same domain

Tags: magento-1.7, customer

How can I pass the customer session and information from Magento  to Codeigniter in same domain. In codeigniter I have created a function to check the customer session then if the customer is logged in then returning the customer information or else redirecting to magento customer login page if not.

In codeigniter Created a function as

```
public function loggedIn(){

    //$customerInfo = array();
    $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $fullPath = $dir.'/magento/app/Mage.php';
    echo $fullPath;

    require_once( "$fullPath" );
    umask(0);

    // Initialize Magento
    Mage::app();

    // You have two options here,
    // “frontend” for frontend session or “adminhtml” for admin session
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
    $customer_data = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCustomer();
    if($session->isLoggedIn()){
    echo "Logged In";
    var_dump($customer_data);
    }
    else{
    echo "Logged out";
    header('Location:http://localhost/magento/customer/account');
   // Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(""); 

    }

 }
```

When customer is loggedIn in magento then it shows "Logged In" and for logged out user it is redirecting. However, it is not showing any logged in user information.

I had tried both-- getSingleton('customer/session') and `getModel('customer/customer');` but it is not returning any value. And How can I use entire magento functionality in there. I am not able to use redirect function as well so just used PHP header function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a not getting the customer from the session. You are creating an instance of the customer model and calling a method that returns `null`. `getCustomer` is the same as `getData('customer')` on the customer model. This is always null.
Try it like this:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
if ($session->isLoggedIn()) { //if the customer is logged in
    return $session->getCustomer();
}
else {
    //the customer is not logged in
    return false;//or do what ever you want for this case
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please explain a bit where I was wrong once again. if in place of customer session can I use customer model to check customer login and information?

Comment: Why customer model was returning Null values ?? :(

Comment: @MagentoBoy I just explained in the answer. Calling `Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCustomer();` will  call in `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::getCustomer`, The method does not exist so you end up calling `__call` in the customer model. and `getCustomer` translates into `getData('customer')` that returns `_data['customer']` which is empty because you have a clean instance of the model. You need to get the customer from the session.

Comment: ...Nice explanation.. Thank you and one more thing... When customer logged out I am redirecting to login page where I use the magento functions            $url ="http://localhost/magento/customer/account";    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect("$url"); but it is not redirecting and not showing any error as well.

Comment: Post an other question for this. It's off topic on this question. Also other people might find it easier.